# Android Studio ListView Only 1 Time Clickable

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview, onitemclicklistener

I created a class "users" and i add the some names.
Next i created a ArrayAdapter for ListView and i connect them.
But i wont items only one time clickable. I couldn't.
How can i, in listview items only once time clickable?
Show it with a sample code please?

```
//Adapter
        //ListView Adapter
        ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.list_user,
                usersArrayList.stream().map(users -> users.name).collect(Collectors.toList()));
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainScreenActivity.this, PointActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("Userr", usersArrayList.get(i));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

Comment: you can use boolean ie- you set true in the first click and false in the second click and check the condition before on click does that boolean is true or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done in a few ways. But the simplest way for your case is to add a boolean field for clicked items. But note that you need to manage this filed depending on your need. For example if you want the items to be clickable every time your app starts then initially you must set that clicked variables of each user to false.

User class

```java
public class User {
    //...
    public boolean clicked;
    //...
}
```

In the activity where you setup the on item click listener

```java
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        User user = usersArrayList.get(i);
        if(user == null) {
            // Make a Log here informing that the user object null
            return; // Don't proceed
        }
        if(user.clicked) return; // This user is already clicked, don't proceed
        // If the user is not clicked then set the clicked to true and proceed
        user.clicked = true;
        // You may want to save or update the modified user here
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainScreenActivity.this, PointActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("Userr", user);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

If you use database or something else and you want to save a user's clicked state, don't forget to save or update the modified user object every time you modify the clicked property.

Comment: How can I reach you for a solution to a different problem? Mail?

Comment: Hi, you can post your new question in stackoverflow and give me its link in comments here.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72503018/which-user-is-logged-in-webview

Answer (score 0):

You can add one boolean flag to your Users class. Once you click on the specific item first time, just set that flag to true and check it every time that flag is true or false. if false then handle the tap event else ignore it.

Hope this will help you.

Regards,
ABV

Comment: i tried to do this but it didn't work "listView.setEnabled(false);" in .setOnItemClickListener its do it all listView un clickable.

Comment: No not like this. You can add one boolean to Users class where you have added name. And update flag of users class based on user click the item.

Answer (score 0):

Like,

```
Class User{

.....
bool isItemClicked = false;
}

//Adapter
        //ListView Adapter
        ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.list_user,
                usersArrayList.stream().map(users -> users.name).collect(Collectors.toList()));
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
User clickedUser = usersArrayList.get(i);
if(!clickedUser.isItemClicked ){
clickedUser.isItemClicked = true;
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainScreenActivity.this, PointActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("Userr", usersArrayList.get(i));
                startActivity(intent);}
            }
        });
```